# URL design for a proxy API

Tags: rest, api, mule, mulesoft

We have multiple API's running for an enterprise. As per our limitation client will allow only one static IP to receive all Inbound/Outbound requests.

So, we need to expose a single API as a bridge between the client system and API's running behind.

How to approach this design?
How to design the URL for this proxy API?
What edge functions does this API need to provide?

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to send SOAP body to proxy ? or just headers, Uri params etc. ?

Comment: All are REST API's and I need to send whole payload along with all header

Comment: what you mean by whole payload, is it XML payload do u need to send it to proxy request along with headers ?

Comment: Yes, I need to pass all the attributes and JSON payload to the client system via proxy.

Comment: Do you want just to have a white list of consumers ips for your APIs ?

Comment: What solution did you use ?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use web services consumer, yet will need to create a POC.

Define A RAML with required path and RAML, scaffolding should give you API took kit, and connect an `HTTP request`

use `HTTP request`
Examples:

Define `Headers` ---  `attributes.headers.id` etc 
     queryParams  ----   `attributes.queryParams.date`

if you are sending JSON payload across from ex: postman, change Mime type to `application/json`

sample http properties for request

```
http.host=myHost
http.port=8872
http.base.path=/myproxy/services
```